# NestedScrollView with constraint layout as child not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I want to scroll the whole layout above keyboard but its not working. I was able to scroll manually but want it to scroll
programatically when a user sets focus on the edit text.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
......

edit_text_code.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->

            if (hasFocus) {

                scrollView.post {

                    scrollView.fullScroll(NestedScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

First get the x/y coordinates of your Edittext using [View.getLocationOnScreen (int[] location)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) ( After the method returns, the array contains the x and y location in that order)

Then do :

```
scrollView.scrollTo(x, y);
```

If above method doesn't work try below method :

**Method 2:**

```
 edit_text_code.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // put your edit text id below
            if (view.getId() ==R.id.DwEdit) {
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**XML Code :**

```
 <EditText
android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minLines="10"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:inputType="textCapSentences">
</EditText>
```

Comment: Hi @marsuser does above solution help you in solving your issue ?